# How to create a nested And/Or Condition in mongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below SQL query,

```
SELECT *
      FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[EmpTbl] WHERE 
      (EmpDept='IT' and EmpDept='Account') 
      OR (EmpDept='HR' or EmpDept='Finance') 
      AND (EmpDept='Sales' or EmpDept='Admin')
```

How can I write the equivalent query for mongoDB?

Comment: Please post a sample document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I don't understand your document structure but as per your question I created following documents

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547bfbc78849d6c59671b8e3"), "EmpDept" : "IT" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547bfbce8849d6c59671b8e4"), "EmpDept" : "Account" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547bfbd48849d6c59671b8e5"), "EmpDept" : "HR" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547bfbdb8849d6c59671b8e6"), "EmpDept" : "Finance" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547bfbe38849d6c59671b8e7"), "EmpDept" : "Sales" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547bfbeb8849d6c59671b8e8"), "EmpDept" : "Admin" }
```

And query for obtaining result as below

```
db.collectionName.find({
"$and": [
    {
        "EmpDept": "IT",
        "EmpDept": "Account"
    },
    {
        "$or": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "EmpDept": "HR",
                        "EmpDept": "Finance"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "EmpDept": "Sales",
                        "EmpDept": "Admin"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
})
```

Comment: I believe that is incorrect syntax: the first $or is not actually an $or since it only has one condition and the last nested $and is redundant

Comment: query give me error like Duplicate element name.
actually after creating a query i will convert it into bsonDocument and then use aggregate function on them.so how can i achive this.

Comment: can you post your document structure or expected output from documents?

Comment: i have excel file which will uploaded in mongodb. The document structure is.
  "ID" : 1,
  "Discovery_Month_Year" : "May-11",
  "Complete_Incomplete" : "",
  "Portal" : "",
  "Commercial_resi" : "",
  "Meeting_Not_Yet_Yes_0" : "",
  "Sample_Flat" : "No",
  "Project_Name" : "",
  "Place" : "",
  "Area" : "",
  "Stop" : "",
  "Builder_Group" : "",
  "Builder_Category" : "",
  "Stage_of_Construction" : "",
  "No_of_towers" : 1,
  "Floor" : 30,
  "Approx_tonnage" : 0,
  "Pitching_Product" : "",
  "Builder_Name" : "",
  "Builder_contact_no" : "",
  "Final_Status" : "Prospecting",
}

Comment: please use Final_Status Instead of EmpDept.